# Session cookie not persisting with JSoup

Tags: android, cookies, jsoup, kotlin

I've been creating an Android app which logs into and scrapes a website. Unfortunately, I've been having problems with JSoup and persisting session cookies.

Whenever I try to make a POST request, the website will complain that the session has expired. I've isolated the cause of the problem to the `JSESSIONID` cookie (since deleting it on a browser while trying to log in gives the same result). However, even if I include all previous cookies using the `.cookies()` method, the website will still complain that the session has expired.

I am wondering if I am making any obvious mistakes that are stopping my app from maintaining a session properly.

The relevant portion of my code so far *(note: I'm using Kotlin for this project)*:

```
val url = "omitted here"
val username = "user"
val password = "hunter2"

val initial = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .method(Connection.Method.GET).execute()

val cookies = initial.cookies()

val login = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .userAgent("Mozilla")
            .data("login_name", username)
            .data("password", password)
            .cookies(cookies)
            .post()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Based on comments, it is likely not a Kotlin issue at all and instead that the page does not return cookies from the server, but rather later via JavaScript.    Turn off JavaScript in your web browser and see if you still get a cookie in the web browser.  I don't think we could do more without knowing the page you are trying to access.  But then we would be debugging your page for you instead of answering this question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct assuming the cookies are set by the server and not via JavaScript later.  Assuming no missing code the cookies should be going into the second request.  It could be that you misinterpret how the site works and how it uses the cookies, and maybe that it does not assign a valid cookie until login and always complains about "session expired" on any non-logged in cookie.   Maybe not a code bug at all, but a logic problem.

But your full code *could* also be wrong if you don't take something into account the following:

You need to remember, that the Jsoup library only returns cookies for a request when that specific request receives a `Set-Cookie` header from the server.  It does *not* return the list of "all known cookies".  Therefore you have to maintain a map that is an ongoing accumulation of each cookie response.

Think of the `response.cookies()` method as actually being `response.newCookiesAddedFromThisRequest()`. The code pattern is:

```
val cookies = mutableMapOf<String, String>()

val initialResponse = Jsoup.connect("http://www.whatarecookies.com/cookietest.asp")
    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
    .cookies(cookies)
    .execute()
cookies.putAll(initialResponse.cookies())

val secondResponse = Jsoup.connect("http://www.whatarecookies.com/cookietest.asp")
    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
    .cookies(cookies)
    .execute()
cookies.putAll(secondResponse.cookies()) 

// `cookies` now contains all cookies added accumulatively
```

In this code, the returned new cookies are added each time to a managed Map of cookies, and the totality of all cookies are sent each request.

**Also note:**  Jsoup does not process cookies in header order therefore sometimes the wrong value is set for a cookie.  It also can sometimes leave cookie values as null on accident.  You should check the [known cookie issues](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20cookie) for Jsoup.  An alternative is to use something like [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) to do the retrieval of the document, and then parse it using Jsoup.  Jsoup does not have a focus on the HTTP protocol as much as they do on the HTML parsing and manipulation.

Comment: I've tried both your code solution and using OkHttp for making the requests, but no dice on either... I've also tried adding another GET request to a protected resource after my form POST to see if the correct cookies were being set after the fact, but that also hasn't worked; I can only assume the server is doing something bizarre with its handling of cookies

Comment: If they are cookies from the server, you'd see them in JSoup in one way or another.  It does nothing to filter and just shoves them in the response.  Therefore they could be JavaScript added cookies.  You might need to use a server-side scraping system that uses a full browser to process requests and return final page after all scripts complete.  That's a whole different thing....

Comment: I tried logging into the page with NoScript and it worked perfectly... I'm at a  complete loss at this point, so I'll try out Selendroid (or may just use a WebView). Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: @cmdd check the headers coming back when using Chrome or a browser debugging window that lets you see such things and see what headers are coming back.  It'll be a clue.  The same for the headers coming back from your app to see if they differ.  Maybe the site blocks if something else isn't "right" to it?

Comment: Update: For curiosity's sake, I've tried using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to send a post request to the site in question, using its Interceptor extension to capture the exact request parameters as when logging in on a browser normally. After making the request, I was still getting the same session errors. (side note: I noticed that logging in through a browser redirected me through another page before leaving me at the "logged in home page," however I tried setting `.followRequests(true)` on my Jsoup request and no dice...